# C# delete database ms.access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have problem delete data microsoft access database with C#
I use this method to add data to microsoft access database

```
public static int autoIncrement(string kalimatSql)
{
    int lastIndex = -1;
    dbCon.Open();
    dbCmd.CommandText = kalimatSql;
    dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dbCmd.CommandText = "Select @@Identity";
    lastIndex = Convert.ToInt32(dbCmd.ExecuteScalar());
    dbCon.Close();
    return lastIndex;
}
```

I call that method with

```
myQuiz.id = Global.autoIncrement("INSERT INTO Quizzes (Name) VALUES ('" + myQuiz.name + "')");
Global.quizzes.Add(myQuiz);
```

I wonder how to delete data from database? if I add with that way?
So far I already try this way

```
public static int deleteData(string kalimatSQL)
{
    int lastIndex = -1;
    dbCon.Open();
    dbCmd.CommandText = kalimatSQL;
    dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dbCon.Close();
    return lastIndex;
}
```

And I call delete method with this way

```
if ( listBoxQuizzes.SelectedIndex != -1)  {
    Global.deleteData("DELETE FROM Quizzes WHERE name=" +listBoxQuizzes.SelectedItem.ToString()); 
}
```

But give error result

> "C# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'name = quiz002' "
>   can someone help me fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing single quotes around name value (`''`)

It should be like this:

```
Global.deleteData("DELETE FROM Quizzes WHERE name = '" + listBoxQuizzes.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'");
```

Comment: u're right
thanks for helped...i will mark u answer as correct one